# C++ : Error does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment to create a MIPS Simulator in C++. I got
 error: 'temporaries' does not name a type
 error: 'saved' does not name a type
I am just implementing the arithmetic part and am using three files, main.cpp, al.cpp, al.h.

al.h

```c
#ifndef AL_H
#define AL_H
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

int *temporaries;
int *saved;

typedef struct
{
  std::string name;
  int value;
}label;

//function declarations

#endif
```

main.cpp

```c
#include "al.h"
#include<fstream>
std::vector<label> labels;
temporaries=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
saved=malloc(10*sizeof(int));

//main()
```

al.cpp

```c
#include "al.h"
using namespace std;
//function definitions
```

I am using g++

```
g++ al.cpp main.cpp al.h
```

I am just a beginner in progamming. It will be great if anyone can help me out.

**Edit**

Used `extern` in the header files and declared the variables in the source files just like paddy showed and it was fixed.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Why use `int* saved` instead of `std::vector<int> saved`? Do you actually want global variables (if you don't understand the question the answer is no)? If you really want to `malloc` for some reason then you'll need to cast `static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(10 * sizeof *saved))`. In C++ you can just have `struct label` you don't need to do the typedef thing.

Comment: I think that 'saved' should be a global variable as I am changing it in 'al.cpp' as well as in 'main.cpp'. As for malloc, I just thought of it as a way to initialise 'saved'. I did use 'vector<int> saved' in 'al.h' and 'saved.resize(10)' in 'main.cpp' before, but I got the same error.

Comment: You can create a variable in main and pass it to other functions, or if they are related, but them in a `class` together. global variables are (almost) never the answer. `malloc` is a very low-level solution which doesn't seem necessary (and is a headache for new programmers). If you know your types are a fixed size you could just use a `std::array<int, 10> saved` as well.

Comment: @RyanHaining 
Final version used vectors. So, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do the assignment at the global scope level, unless it is initialising a type.  That's what the error messages are trying to tell you.

The quick fix is to put it in your main function:

```
int main()
{
    temporaries=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    saved=malloc(10*sizeof(int));

    // Other program logic here...

    return 0;
}
```

But note that you have a problem with the declaration in the header file.  The version of `temporaries` and `saved` visible within `al.cpp` is not the same as in `main.cpp`.  In order to achieve that, you need something like this:

**al.h**

```
extern int *temporaries;
extern int *saved;

void al_init();
```

**al.cpp**

```
// These are the actual symbols referred to by the extern
int *temporaries = nullptr;
int *saved = nullptr;

// Since these belong to `al`, initialize them in that same source unit.
void al_init()
{
    temporaries=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    saved=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    al_init();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, now we're getting a strange blend of C and C++ style, and I'm going to stop going down this rabbit hole.   Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: I suspect OP is using globals because they don't have *anything* inside of a function, not because they actually want globals.

Comment: Yeah it's possible that there is a confusion over why one would put variables in a header file.  I've taken it at face value: they are in the header file, therefore they are part of that unit's interface, therefore they should be extern.  If not, then they should not be in the header.

Comment: you'll need a cast on those malloc calls too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: your code needs to be inside a function¹, i.e. `main()` (you need it in your program² anyway, if you haven't defined it already).

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<label> labels;
    temporaries = static_cast<int*>(malloc(10*sizeof *temporaries));
    saved = static_cast<int*>(malloc(10*sizeof *saved));
}
```

¹ some code can be executed at global scope, but that's beyond purview of this question

² sans freestanding environment

Comment: ... or any function not directly or indirectly called by `main()`. That's not a requirement, so don't overstate this.

Comment: I'll rephrase it. It's advice directed at a newbie, though.

Comment: *"Needs to be inside a function"* is newbie-friendly, and shorter, and more correct.

Comment: The (purportedly) missing `main()` function is unrelated to the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I hope I clarified it now.

Comment: `static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(10 * sizeof *temporaries))`

Comment: Since this is C++ already, I do wonder why I've never seen `static_cast<T*>(malloc(N * sizeof(decltype(variable)))`.

Comment: @krzaq because you can do `sizeof *variable` instead of (what I think you mean) `sizeof(decltype(*variable))`.  To be pedantic, if you use `<cstdlib>` you should be using `std::malloc`